# HTML5 widget ERROR event

Tags: html, events, widget, soundcloud

Is there a event `SC.Widget.Events.ERROR` — fired when for some reason the track could not be loaded or any other error occurred?

This happens some time on flash widget, so it's a nice event to skip the track, and go to next one.

Comment: To clarify yvg's answer, no there is no such event, but it is now on our roadmap. Keep an eye on the documentation, since this will be updated when that is added. http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/html5-widget

Answer (score 0):

We might look into implementing this on the HTML5 Widget.

Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: i looked into implementing HTML5 widget and there was no event documented. The reason I was asking was that sometime the docs on soundcloud apis are missing some stuff.

Comment: any news on implementing the event?